# Can't run ember serve because jQuery unexpected token

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I installed ember-cli and node.js

after I type `ember serve` I stuck because jQuery.

```
SyntaxError: color-app/static/lib/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)
// you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
//"use strict";
```

How do I solve this problem?

I did nothing after `ember new` command.

my package versions..

```
ember-cli: 2.4.3
node: 4.4.2
os: darwin x64
```

Comment: Do 'ember new' again and see if the problem persists.

Comment: no it's not answer for me.. I remove node.js and reinstall ember.